# How to query data using 'useQueries' when it is dependent on previous query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am creating a webapp where I can show a list of Pokemons on initial page load using [PokéAPI](https://pokeapi.co/). The list should show all the images of the Pokemons and its name, inside of an MUI Card, something like this: [App UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLu25.png).

I am using two APIs. One for getting the list of all the [Pokemon names and their details](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0). Another for getting the [specific Pokemon's image](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto).

In order to create the UI, I am querying the first API to get the list of all the Pokemons. And then I am using the result of the first API in the second query to get the image of that Pokemon.

Here are both the components that I have created:

`PokemonList.jsx`

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { useQueries, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";

const getPokemonList = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=12&offset=0"
  );
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

const usePokemonList = () => {
  return useQuery(["pokemonList"], () => getPokemonList());
};

const getPokemons = async (url) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url);
  return data;
};

const usePokemons = (pokemons) => {
  return useQueries({
    queries: pokemons?.results.map((pokemon) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["pokemons", pokemon.name],
        queryFn: getPokemons.bind(this, pokemon.url),
        staleTime: Infinity,
        enabled: !!pokemons.count,
      };
    }),
  });
};

function PokemonList() {
  const { data: pokemonList } = usePokemonList();
  const { data: pokemons, isLoading } = usePokemons(pokemonList);
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        flexFlow: "row wrap",
        gap: "2em",
      }}
    >
      {!isLoading &&
        pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
          <PokemonCard
            key={pokemon.species.name}
            name={pokemon.species.name}
            image={pokemon.sprites.front_default}
          />
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
}

export default PokemonList;
```

`PokemonCard.jsx`

```
import { Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

PokemonCard.propTypes = {
  image: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

function PokemonCard(props) {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ width: 225, flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
      <CardMedia component="img" height="140" image={props.image} />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="caption">{props.name}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmENY.png) that I am getting, because the first API has not resolved yet. What should be the proper way to use `useQueries` here?

Comment: `queries: pokemons?.results?.map` make this change I think results is undefined

Comment: I also tried that. It is showing the same error message. Didn't work. `pokemons` is undefined here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that the thing you're trying to map for your `useQueries` call is null or undefined. Which makes sense if the previous result has not yet returned. Additionally your hooks are a little too brittle in how their integrated. I would suggest refactoring your `usePokemons` hook to just take a list of pokemons (not an object with results) and default it to being empty. e.g.

```js
const usePokemons = (pokemons) => {
  pokemons = pokemons || [];
  return useQueries({
    queries: pokemons.map((pokemon) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["pokemons", pokemon.name],
        queryFn: getPokemons.bind(this, pokemon.url),
        staleTime: Infinity,
      };
    }),
  });
};
```

Then you just change how you integrate the two:

```js
function PokemonList() {
  const { data: pokemonList, isLoading: isListLoading } = usePokemonList();
  const { data: pokemons, isLoading: isImagesLoading } = usePokemons(pokemonList?.results);
// ... etc
```